# Can python popen capture interactive output of a subprocess of a subprocess

Tags: python, jython, pexpect, installanywhere

We have an app named app.exe which in turn is a wrapper for a java.exe for the installanywhere launcher.
Suppose we have a python script a.py which calls app.exe which then spawns the java.exe process, how do we capture the interactive outputs and inputs between a.py and java.exe

Can Popen do that ?
Are there simple examples we could read more to follow ?
Can pexpect be used in this scenario too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's possible if your *a.exe* redirects its own stdin to *java.exe* stdin and *java.exe* stdout to its own *stdout*.

Have a look at [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). There are 2 optional arguments: *stdin* controlling subproces's standard input and *stdout*, which controls subproces's standard output.

Comment: Hi Maksym thanks for responding; could you provide a sample to show how this works ?

Comment: @chz I have updated my answer. Actually I know nothing about your a.exe file and can say nothing about its stdin/stdout.